# How to compute the probability of finding a given state in the $|+\rangle$ state?

Tags: quantum-state, measurement

Consider the state
$$
\left| \varphi \right>=\frac{i}{\sqrt{3}} \left| 0 \right> + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}} \left| 1\right>.
$$
What is the probability of qubit system when measured in the state $\left| + \right>$?

Comment: Base must contain 2 states.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is known that:

$$
\left| 0 \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left| + \right\rangle + \left| - \right\rangle \right)
\qquad
\left| 1 \right\rangle = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \left( \left| + \right\rangle - \left| - \right\rangle \right)
$$

By substituting in the initial state:

$$
\left| \varphi \right\rangle = \frac{i}{\sqrt{3}}\left| 0 \right\rangle + \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}}\left| 1 \right\rangle = 
\frac{i + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{6}} \left| + \right\rangle + 
\frac{i - \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{6}} \left| - \right\rangle
$$

So the probability to measure the qubit in the $\left| + \right\rangle$ state is equal to $\left|\frac{i + \sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{6}}\right|^2 = 0.5$